# Realm method "Cannot Resolve Symbol"

Tags: android, realm, cannot-find-symbol

I'm using Realm for Android to create a database for my app but wheme i go to try to call the method `realm.beginTrasnaction()`, it tell me that Android Studio cannot resolve symbol.

Here's my piece of code:

```
import io.realm.Realm;

public class playerCreator {

Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.beginTransaction();

}
```

And here's my gradle files:

Project Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tfdev.avventuratestuale"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Does anybody know how can i use realm.beginTransaction() ?

Comment: Where is your constructor or even methods? You can not simply drop your lines into a class without placing them to their respectively places.

Comment: Do you mean i need to build Realm realm?

Comment: I'm following official  Realm tutorial

Comment: You need to call that method inside a method, not just randomly in a class - `official Realm tutorial` I do not know of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've fixxed added the constructor of my playerCreator class, thanks to Murat K.

```
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class playerCreator extends RealmObject{

    public playerCreator(){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.beginTransaction();

    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to crash the moment you call `realm.createObject(playerCreator.class)`. Then again, this doesn't sound like something that would store data, soo.... why does it `extends RealmObject`? Have you read the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances)?